# Transpose Datagrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, transpose

I would like to have a datagrid that is transposed in flex. I believe I can do this with an OLAP datagrid but this seems a bit heavy weight. I just want a standard datagrid with a different orientation.

For example a datagrid looks like:

- Header1|Header2
- val1|val2
- val3|val4

but I would like

Header1| val1 | val3
Header2| val2 | val4

Is this possible using a standard datagrid? I couldnt see much on Google apart from the olap datagrid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here on StackOverflow...

My search parameters were just a bit wrong.

[Flex Vertical Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214084/flex-vertical-datagrid)